# Dropping thousands tables make database slow

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on some issue where I am creating thousands of tables and doing some testing.

In next iteration i am dropping those tables and again regenerating it. But with these steps, my database becomes very slow.

Even its my local database where i am only working, so its only effect of dropping tables multiple times.

Anyone have any idea to improve the database performance in this scenario. I am dropping these table from PL/SQL developer using UI.

I am using Oracle 11g.
Thanks

Comment: are you dropping them with the PURGE option?

Comment: I am selecting those column in PL/SQL developer and using right click, performing the Drop option. I don't know how PL/SQL doing internally.

Comment: Why do you create thousands of tables? Do you need some temporary tables? If you come from a SQL Server background and are used to creating and dropping temporary tables - don't do that in Oracle. Use "real" temporary tables instead.

Comment: First time working on database. What is real temporary tables?

Comment: @CrazyC: What type of tables you are creating. its a simple table or tables with relations?

Comment: Here's a reference to an [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:48812348054) question/answer about Oracle temporary tables.

Comment: @HariHaran, these are simple table without any index and key.

Comment: @CrazyC: As per my understanding, you are creating 1000 tables and doing some steps. AFter that you drop all the 1000 tables. Next time you again create 1000 table and do the same process. Is my understanding correct?   If "Yes". Then once you create 1000 tables and done your first iteration process. Just truncate the 1000 tables. Truncate will not delete the table, it will clear the table data. so for next iteration you can re-use the same table.

Comment: why would you need thousands of tables? Sorry to be curious but what's the point of all this?

Answer (score 1):

The main bottleneck is probably the PL/SQL Developer GUI.  It can be quite slow when dealing with a large number of objects or windows.

For example, when I created 1000 tables:

```
begin
    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
        execute immediate 'create table table'||lpad(i,4,'0')||'(a number)';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

It took 70 seconds to drop them from the GUI, but only 20 seconds with this script:

```
begin
    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
        execute immediate 'drop table table'||lpad(i,4,'0');
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: +1. Do it with the GUI if you're not planning on doing it again. Otherwise script it for future reruns. Of course, asking why you're repeatedly creating and dropping 1000s of tables would be a good idea as well :)